# how to change dataType json to local after dataLoad for searchFilter

Tags: jquery, json, web, jqgrid

It doesn't work searchFilter. I send some paramData to server side and then server response to json data. Sorting is work but can't use search. I try many time pix this problem but i don't know how to that. Some people said searchFilter should be dataType 'local'. But i receive json from server cuz can't use local type. if someone know how to pix this one let me know how to change that code, please!

here is my script code!

function jqgridWrite(){

```
var param = $('#playerInfo').serialize();
$("#gridfield").empty();   
var a = $("<table>").attr("id", "multiple");  
var b = $("<div>").attr("id", "pmultiple");
$("#gridfield").append(a); 
$("#gridfield").append(b);

    jQuery("#multiple").jqGrid({
    url:'playerGrid.do',
    postData: param,
        datatype: "json",
    colNames:['이름','포지션','소속팀', '평점','출전시간','MoM','선발','교체','득점','도움',
              '키패스','총슈팅','유효슈팅','프리킥','패널트킥','총패스','짧은패스','롱패스','크로스',
              '쓰루패스','헤딩','드리블','볼터치','태클','반칙','피반칙','오프사이드','옐로우카드',
              '레드카드'
              ],
    colModel:[
        {name:'playerName', index:'playerNamed', width:60, align:'center', search:true, sorttype:"text", key:true},
        {name : 'playerPosition', width:80, align:'center' , formatter : function(cellValue,options,rowObject){
            if(cellValue == 'CF'){
                 return '중앙공격수';
            }else if(cellValue== 'ST'){
                 return '스트라이커';
            }else if(cellValue== 'RWF'){
                 return '오른쪽윙포워드';
            }else if(cellValue== 'LWF'){
                 return '왼쪽윙포워드';
            }else if(cellValue== 'AM'){
                 return '공격형미드';
            }else if(cellValue== 'CM'){
                 return '중앙미드';
            }else if(cellValue== 'LM'){
                 return '왼쪽미드';
            }else if(cellValue== 'RM'){
                 return '오른쪽미드';
            }else if(cellValue== 'DM'){
                return '수비형미드';
            }else if(cellValue== 'LB'){
                return '왼쪽수비수';
            }else if(cellValue== 'RB'){
                return '오른쪽수비수';
            }else if(cellValue== 'CB'){
                 return '중앙수비수';
            }else if(cellValue== 'LWB'){
                 return '왼쪽윙백';
            }else if(cellValue== 'RWB'){
                 return '오른쪽윙백';
            }else if(cellValue== 'GK'){
                 return '골키퍼';
            }
        }}, 
        {name:'playerTeam', width:75, align:'center'},
        {name:'playerRate', width:40, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},
        {name:'playTime', width:70, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},     
        {name:'playerMom', width:40, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},        
        {name:'playerAppearance', width:30, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},
        {name:'playerSubstitute', width:30, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},
        {name:'score', width:30, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},
        {name:'assist', width:30, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},
        {name:'keyPass', width:40, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},
        {name:'shotTotal', width:40, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},
        {name:'onTarget', width:50, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},
        {name:'freekick', width:40, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},
        {name:'penalty', width:50, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},
        {name:'passTotal', width:40, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},
        {name:'shortPass', width:50, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},
        {name:'longPass', width:40, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},
        {name:'crossPass', width:40, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},
        {name:'throughPass', width:50, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},
        {name:'header', width:30, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},
        {name:'dribble', width:40, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},
        {name:'ballTouch', width:40, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},
        {name:'tackle', width:30, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},
        {name:'foul', width:30, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},
        {name:'fouled', width:40, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},
        {name:'offside', width:55, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},
        {name:'yellowCard', width:55, align:"center", sorttype:"number"},
        {name:'redCard', width:50, align:"center", sorttype:"number"}
    ],
    page: 1,
    rowNum:2,
    rownumbers: true,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    height:"100%",
    width:1855,
    pager: '#pmultiple',
    sortname: 'playerRate',
    mtype:"POST",
    gridview: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    loadonce: true,
    caption: "선수기록",
    jsonReader : {repeatitems:false},
    loadComplete: function () {
            jQuery("#multiple").jqGrid({datatype: "local"});

    }
});
 $('#multiple').navGrid("#pmultiple", {                
         search: true, // show search button on the toolbar
         add: false,
         edit: false,
         del: false,
         refresh: true
     },
     {}, // edit options
     {}, // add options
     {}, // delete options
     { multipleSearch: true } // search options - define multiple search
 );
```

}

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use? The option `loadonce: true` changes the `datatype` to `"local"` after the first loading. By the way the code contains no `datatype` option and the default `"xml"` should be used instead of `"json"` (only free jqGrid should guess `"json"` because you use `jsonReader` option). **Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? The searching in `playerName` will not work because of `index: 'playerNamed'`.

Comment: You can use `formatter: "select"` in the column `playerPosition` (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#formatter_type_select)). If you would prefer to use custom formatter then you should define unformatter too (see [unformat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting)). Do you have problem in searching in all columns or only in the first two columns which are defined incorrectly? In case of general problem you should post some test data (2-3 rows of data), which can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Oleg thank you, you're so awesome!!! I fix it that problem ! Sorry for late comment, thx again!